# Une variante pour le mot « opération » en mathématiques

Tags: terminologie, mathématiques, néerlandais, demande-de-mot

En français, on utilise le mot *opération*. Il désigne surtout une loi interne, un produit matriciel, une fonction sur la droite réelle, ou quelque chose de semblable. En néerlandais, j’emploie le mot « operatie » en guise de traduction.

Néanmoins, il ne me semble pas possible de l’utiliser s’il s’agit de petits façonnages comme un changement d’échelle, ajouter un nombre où diviser un vecteur par sa longueur. Selon moi, un mot modique conviendrait mieux que l’expression « operatie », qui détonne légèrement, car elle parait quelque peu boursoufflée. Au lieu de cette expression, on emploie donc le nom « bewerking » au fur et à mesure. La meilleure traduction est vraisemblablement *remaniement*, et ce nom parait moins pesant que « operatie », puisqu’une opération mérite plutôt d’être utilisée pour décrire de grandes choses comme la fonction Gamma, ou pour nommer un plongement dans un ensemble de morphismes d’anneaux. 
Quant à *opération*, je ne suis pas au courant quel esprit peut gésir au-dessous.

J’espère que vous pouvez me répondre.
S’il y a un mot qui a cours dans le langage mathématique, je suis preneur. Dans le cas où je me suis trompé en pensant que l’emploi *opération* est borné aux petites fonctions, je voudrais aussi le savoir. Je serais également content d’apprendre qu’*opération* est le seul mot qui convient à ce que je tente d’exprimer.

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûr de comprendre ce que tu veux dire par « boursouflée », lourde de connotations ?

Comment: Oui, lourde de connotations

Comment: En français, on emploie que très rarement (voire jamais) *opération* pour désigner une fonction. Selon les goûts et les domaines, on préfère en général *fonction* ou *application* ou des noms plus précis comme *opérateur*, *morphisme*, *transformée*, *injection*… et on réserve *opération* à celles qui se notent en infixe, comme ⋅+⋅ ou ⋅×⋅ (et éventuellement les produits scalaires ⟨⋅|⋅⟩). En tout cas l'ampleur du « façonnage » n'a pas d'influence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Après quelques recherches, voici les candidats que je retiens :

> *Opération* : En mathématiques, une opération est un processus visant à obtenir un résultat à partir d'un ou plusieurs objets appelés opérandes. [1](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Op%C3%A9ration_%28math%C3%A9matiques%29) Noter qu'en Géométrie, ces *opérations* sont appelées *transformations*.
>
> *Application* : En mathématiques, une application est une relation entre deux ensembles pour laquelle chaque élément du premier (appelé ensemble de départ ou source) est relié à un unique élément du second (l’ensemble d'arrivée ou but). [2](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_%28math%C3%A9matiques%29)
>
> *Fonction* : une fonction relie deux grandeurs (a priori numériques) de telle façon que la connaissance de la première permet de déterminer la deuxième. [3](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction)
>
> *Relation* : [...] Les fonctions ou applications peuvent être vues elles-mêmes comme des cas particuliers de relations. Plus précisément une fonction (application) n-aire est une relation n+1 fonctionnelle (et applicative).[4](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_%28math%C3%A9matiques%29)

Bien que techniquement tous ces termes soient des mots français, on sort un peu des compétences de linguistes : je vous laisse donc choisir le terme qui vous convient le mieux !

Answer (score 3):

On ne parle jamais de remaniement en math. Je pense qu'à la place d'opération (si vraiment c'est inadapté, ce qui ne me paraît pas évident en général), on utiliserait en fait un mot qui dépend de la modification en question. Transformation, comme suggéré dans l'autre réponse, fonctionne aussi assez souvent.

Concernant les exemples que tu donnes, pour diviser un vecteur par sa longueur, on parlerait de renormalisation. Changement d'échelle est très bien comme ça ; dans certaines circonstances on utilisera aussi renormalisation.

Un exemple auquel m'a fait penser remaniement : pour modifier l'ordre d'éléments d'un ensemble, on dira réarrangement.